# Renewing U.S passport living in uk

Tags: usa, passport

My U.S passport is over the 15 years expiry date. I DO have a SSN but cannot find it as it was over 20 years since I worked in the US and has been misplaced. I am due to travel to the US soon and am trying to fill in the DS-11 form for an appointment with the embassy. I would like to have all of the information required as I am aware delays or penalties are incurred if missing. Is there a way of accessing your SSN from the UK in time?

Comment: Can't you just say that you lost the card and forgot the number?  They should already have it in their records, after all.

Comment: Your SSN would be on your tax returns. Older pay stubs had the number on them, although more recent ones tend to only have the last 4 digits. If you have any of these stored away, you could find your number. If you have a US bank account, the bank has it (but getting them to tell you what it is may be hard).